# symfony: autowiring an interface

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

What do I need to in order to make this work?

```
interface BaseServiceInterface {
   public function getRecords();
} 

class BaseService implements BaseServiceInterface{
    public function getRecords(){
        return "bla";
    }
}


class SomeOtherService{

    private $baseService;

    public function __construct(BaseServiceInterface $baseService){
         $this->baseService = $baseService;
    }
}
```

my service.yml looks like this:

```
base_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\BaseService
    autowire: true
```

When I try to run this I get:

> Cannot autowire argument 1 for AppBundle\Service\SomeOtherService because the type-hinted class does not exist (Class BaseServiceInterface does not exist).

Comment: did you register the `SomeOtherService` inside the same `service.yml` file? Are all the namespace of those class correct?

Comment: @Federkun yes, when I remove the "Interface" from the constructor=meaning I'm directly injecting the implementation it works. When I try to inject the interface it return an error mentioned above.

Comment: can you try to add `autowiring_types: BaseServiceInterface` to your `base_service`?

Comment: @Federkun yes, I tried that too. It returns the same error

Comment: are you sure that the `BaseServiceInterface` class's namespace inside the `SomeOtherService` file is correct?

Comment: yes. It got somehow cached. I deleted all the cached files and it started to work. Can you post your second answer down below. so I can mark it as "SOLVED"? thanks!

Answer (score 16):

autowire does not work directly with interface.
you need to create the service alias to make it works.

```
services:
    AppBundle\Service\BaseServiceInterface: '@AppBundle\Service\BaseService'
```

reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces